# Does Cubit only works with Stateless Widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, cubit

I am trying to apply this state management but i cannot implement it. If I use stateless widget, i can easily implement it but stateful it is complicated and i cannot achieve it. Where to implement cubits? Here is my code part =>

```
class MaintenanceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int? locId;
  MaintenanceScreen({required this.locId, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MaintenanceScreenState createState() => _MaintenanceScreenState();
}

class _MaintenanceScreenState extends State<MaintenanceScreen> {
  final colFr = FrenchColors();
```

Comment: I think you missed  the rest of the code, please add the full code in case to help.

Comment: @AnasAltarazi i find cubit code example from the Internet. There is always stateless widget. I tried to implement it to my code. It does not happen because it is stateful widget. I cannot implement cubit into stateful widget. Have you any codes to implementing cubit into stateful widget

Comment: There is no difference between using Cubits in stateful or stateless widgets. It is pretty unclear to me, what your actual problem is. Do you get error messages? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I faced the same question. Its not that i have a problem, but whats the dfference between both approaces: 

a) XYZ-Page extends StatelessWidget 
b) XYZ-Page extends state<T>

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you want to access `locId` in `_MaintenanceScreenState`
simply you can use `widget.locId` inside the build function and flutter will bind this with the widget class.

Comment: I know this, I need implementing the cubit into statefulwidget

Comment: normal implement like the stateless widget
what is the problem you are facing when use cubit with stateful widget ?